# Beamer Presentation: Figure has no number?

Tags: beamer, floats, numbering, captions

I am giving a presentation and therefore I am using the [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) class. I have included some figures and it works, but there is no number after "Figure".

My code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{cooltooltips}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{everyshi}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
  }%
  \item[]}{\end{list}} 
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red,bg=white}

\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\normalfont}

\usetheme{Goettingen}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]


%%%
\begin{document}

\frame[plain]{
\titlepage
}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[default]

\frame{
\frametitle{}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{varweakness}
\caption{VaR as a quantile}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

}


\end{document}
```

Which gives the following frame with the figure:

[image: test]

(I am not sure what is causing the problem, therefore I did not delete any package.)

How can I get a number, e.g. `Figure 1:`?

Comment: You should use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}\end{center}`.  Also, you have loaded the `graphicx` package 3 times and `hyperref` twice.  `beamer` I believe automatically loads `graphicx` so you shouldn't need it at all.

Comment: Others have answered your question, but to note the reasoning. In  a presentation, cross-refs by number are usually a bad idea. So the standard `beamer` settings are not to have any such cross-ref numbers.

Comment: @JenBohold Please make your [example minimal](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) the next time.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

To achieve numbering of figures, you need to set:

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{varweakness}
    \caption{VaR as a quantile}
    \label{something}
  \end{figure}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought it was not recommended to use a floating environment (even though it is not floating here) in a presentation. Shouldn't the http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of package be recommended here instead?

Comment: @pluton, I believe that if you put a float inside a frame, it's not going to show up in another slide. The floating freedom is restricted to the other contents in the same frame.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern} % get rid of warnings
\usepackage{caption} % improved spacing between figure and caption

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{horse}{:\quad} % change according to your needs
\captionsetup{
  labelsep = horse,
  figureposition = bottom
} 

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
      \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{Leprechaun.}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that there is no space between the figure number and the colon.