# I can't figure out why my tables are not being numbered

Tags: tables, beamer

I want to have tables with numbers so I can say "`table 1 shows`".. Can you please help?

Example:

```
\documentclass[table,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% \usepackage{beamerthemesplit} // Activate for custom appearance
\usetheme{Berlin}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\frame{%
\frametitle{Calibration}
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Parameter values} % title of Table
\label{table:parametersone}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.3pt}
\small
\scalebox{.65}{\begin{tabular}{l c l c p{8.5cm} } % centered columns (4 columns)         
\hline     %inserts double horizontal lines
\\
Parameter &\phantom{.} & Value  & \phantom{.} & Description \\[1.0ex]    % inserts table 
%heading
\hline             % inserts single horizontal line
\\
$\beta$ &\phantom{.}  & 0.97 &\phantom{.}  & Yearly discount factor   \\ % inserting body of the table
$\alpha$ &\phantom{.}  & 0.60 &\phantom{.}  & Output elasticity of labor  \\
$\gamma$ &\phantom{.}  & 0.10 &\phantom{.}  & Output elasticity of public capital \\
$\theta$ &\phantom{.}  & 2.68 &\phantom{.}  & \parbox{10cm}{Multiplicative factor in the \\
human capital technology} \\
$\psi$ &\phantom{.}  & 0.80 &\phantom{.}  & Parental altruism \\
$\sigma$ &\phantom{.}  & 0.63 &\phantom{.}  & \parbox{12cm}{Exponent on parental human capital} \\
$\phi$ &\phantom{.}  & 0.30 &\phantom{.}  & \parbox{12cm}{Elasticity of the fraction of time during first \\
period spent in school} \\
$\eta$ &\phantom{.}  & 0.10 &\phantom{.}  & \parbox{12cm}{Elasticity on public education expenditures} \\
$\underbar{h}$ &\phantom{.}  & 2.30 &\phantom{.}  & Constant\\
$\lambda$ &\phantom{.}  & 5.00 &\phantom{.}  & \parbox{10cm}{Relative weight of adult labor in production}  \\
$r$ &\phantom{.}  &5.0\% &\phantom{.} & Interest rate \\
$\delta_G$ &\phantom{.}  & 2.5\% &\phantom{.}  & Yearly depreciation rate of public capital\\        % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Captions aren't numbered by default in `beamer`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127150/586

Comment: And to be honest, you don't need numbers when standing in front of the audience saying »This table shows ...«. But in article-mode the captions are shown and you can reference them as usual.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I feel more confident about not having table numbers :)