# Why are figures unnumbered with beamer?

Tags: beamer, numbering, captions

[image]

I have met a simple problem, that why is the figure's number not shown up in beamer?

The code I used is as below,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{grffile,threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig} 
\graphicspath{{F:/}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Ev}
Sty
\begin{figure}[htp] 
    \centering
\caption{Response to}
    \includegraphics[width=3.3in,scale=0.3]{u}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you need numbers for in a presentation? You can easily refer *to the picture on the left*.

Comment: `beamer` does not have floats. `[htp]` is useless and just ignored.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127145/beamer-presentation-figure-has-no-number?rq=1

Comment: @Johannes_B, thanks for your correction for my question!
But I am not sure how to refer to the picture ? Do you mean \ref ?

Comment: No, i mean talking. You are talking to your listeners about what is presented on the slide. There shouldn't be much text on slides.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Frankly speaking, I am not good at it.

Answer (score 39):

This is conceptual rather than technical decision by the original author of `beamer`, Till Tantau. When giving a presentation, the expectation is that the presenter will talk about figures (or other details) whilst they are on the screen. Moving through the talk, referring back to 'Figure X' is unlikely to help as either

- The talk is illustrative and the audience do not have handouts or similar to refer back to
- The talk is for teaching and any vital figures will be *named* or *close by* in the handout

In either case, saying 'As we saw in Figure X' will not be helpful to the audience: if a figure is vital it can be repeated so a visual comparison can be made.

Comment: It is very good!

Comment: it still helps if the audience wants to ask about a figure later on where it was not obvious whether their then-question would not be explained a couple of slides later

Comment: Figures numbers are useful when the theme used doesn't show the frames numbers.  Okay, it is as uneasy to find the `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]` command than the `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]` one, but at least the former doesn't add at the bottom of the frames an extra line (which is annoying with some themes).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I'm in two minds about frame numbers: I've heard reasonable arguments that they simply distract the audience ('Oh, only X slides to go'). My experience is people tend to ask for 'The figure about YYY' rather than 'The one on slide X'.

Comment: When you say 'Oh, only X slides to go', do you mean the case when total number of frames is shown? In such a case, I agree; otherwise, I don't see your point. And I'm not sure to understand what you mean with 'The figure about YYY': what is 'YYY'?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé YYY = 'What the figure is about'. So I might here 'Could you bring up the figure showing the NMR data for your lead compound, it was just before the one showing your other results'.

Comment: Mmmmhhh, a numbered figure would probably be easier for the audience. I just happen to received today presentations from students of mine (who learned LaTeX and Beamer with me) and some of them were speaking so fast and passed by too quickly from one frame to the next one that I was happy when either the figures or the frames had numbers :)

Comment: Your comments are useful!

Comment: Is there any skill to present a report clearly?

Answer (score 26):

However, if you anyway persist to have numbered figures (after reading @Joseph Wright answer at least twice :) ), you need add to preamble:

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
```

i.e.:

```
\documentclass[12pt,xcolor={svgnames},
               hyperref={colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue},
               demo]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{whale}
}
\usepackage{indentfirst,amsmath, multicol,amssymb,threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{grffile,threeparttable}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{{F:/}}

    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]% added

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Ev}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
\caption{Response to}
    \includegraphics[width=3.3in,scale=0.3]{u}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note:

- `beamer` load `graphicx` package itself, so loading it again is superfluous
- `beamer` has own mechanism for caption, so load `caption` package is also superfluous

Comment: @Sebastiano, of course not.

Comment: I was joking 