# Table numbers in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

[image]

I am writing a beamer presentation,but when including tables with \caption then at the left of the title I get "Table: ..." but no table number. Is there a way to get tables numbered? Like "Table 1: ....." and then the one on the next slide "Table 2:...".

Here is my MWE:

```
          \documentclass{beamer}
          \usetheme{Madrid}
          \usepackage{threeparttable}

          \begin{document}
          \begin{frame}{Results}
          \begin{table}[H]
          \centering

          \caption{\smallFertility intentions and measures of employment 
           security and economic uncertainty }


          \scalebox{0.8}{
          \begin{threeparttable}
          \begin{tabular}{lcccc}

          \hline
          \hline
          & (1)   & (2)   & (3)   & (4)  \bigstrut\\
           VARIABLES & Baseline 1 & Baseline 2 & Women & Men   &  

           \hline  \rule{0pt}{3ex}
             % &       &       &      & \bigstrut\\
            Job keeping & 0.0392 & 0.0300 & 0.0656 & -0.0241\\
            & (0.0352) & (0.0362) & (0.0434) & (0.0841) \\
            \hline
          Job seeking & 0.110*** & 0.0944*** & 0.0754* & 0.165**   \\
         & (0.0318) & (0.0321) & (0.0399) & (0.0673)  \\
          \hline
         Financial security & 0.124*** & 0.0942** & 0.0686 & 0.128  \\
        & (0.0438) & (0.0455) & (0.0521) & (0.105)  \\
        \hline
         Social mobility & 0.0751** & 0.0577 & 0.0387 & 0.0909  \\
          & (0.0360) & (0.0358) & (0.0454) & (0.0706)  \\
      \hline

       \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize  Significance levels: *** p$<$0.01, 
       ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1.} \\
       \end{tabular}
       \end{threeparttable}}

       \end{table}

       \end{frame}
       \end{document}
```

Comment: Although refering to the `figure` environment, this question is very similar: [Beamer Presentation: Figure has no number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127145/134144). The solution to add `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]` should solve your problem as well.

Comment: How to get Figure 1 and Table 1 like that? I am getting Figure 1 and then Table 2 ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I could not compile your code, but to get numbered caption, you can use

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
```

in your preamble.

---

Some other comments:

- floating specifier such as `[H]` don't make much sense in a documentclass without floats
- please don't scale elements which contain text, use a smaller font size instead. See also [Why not scale elements that contain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text)
- please consider using the `booktabs` package - it gives much nicer spacing within your table

Comment: thank you, it helps.