# Number of figure in Beamer

Tags: beamer, floats

I'm having the following problem on the beamer:[image]

The resulting frame does not enumerate the figure, ie,
I would like "Figure 1:" to appear instead of "Figure:". I am placing the commands I am using, but if it is placed as `\documentclass{article}` it enumerates normally.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} %para usar simbolos matematicos
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig0}
\caption{Esquematização do problema.}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps the name of the file isnt right?, thats the only warning I see, (since I don't have the fig0), did you try in other document class? running over article, etc, it did mark the figure as Figure 1, so it must be something messing with beamer

Comment: BTW: You neither need the `float` package nor float placements like `[!htb]` in beamer, in beamer `figure` is a non-floating environment anyway (and float placements will be ignored).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the [dustin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127145/beamer-presentation-figure-has-no-number) answer,
all you have to do is

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks to you! I hope you have your work done!